# Using GULP to load Jquery CDN and other external JS sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

I've been trying to find a definitive answer to a problem I'm having using GULP to load the latest jquery CDN or any other Javascript CDN external sources.

What I've got so far is all our JS files being found in a folder, concatenated to a single file and placed in a new folder called min.  Ideally I'd like to also link into the concat process the jquery CDN's and other external js files.

Does anyone know what is the best way to do this?

Here is the code I've got so far:

```html
var gulp = require('gulp');
    var concat = require('gulp-concat');
    var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
    var notify = require('gulp-notify');

    gulp.task('js', function () {
        return gulp.src('js/**/*.js') //select all javascript files under js/ and any subdirectory
            .pipe(concat('mynewfile.min.js')) //the name of the resulting file
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('min')) //the destination folder
            .pipe(notify({ message: 'Finished minifying JavaScript'}));
    });

    gulp.task('watch', function() {
        gulp.watch('js/**/*.js', ['js']);
    });

    gulp.task('default', ['js', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you use the CDN versions? For performance reasons or just to keep an actual version at hand?

Comment: From what I've been told it's to keep the version up to date i.e. when it concats it'll pull down the latest version.

Comment: Ah, in this case you're indeed better off by creating up-to-date copies of the libs, either by checking out the latest (mostly Git) version or using a package manager. Your build shouldn't rely on an online connection anyway, I guess.

Comment: I quote Wikipedia:
“The goal of a CDN is to serve content to end-users with high availability and high performance.”

So this is not about versioning, but mostly faster access to libraries – which are not part of build process – you're assets won't be available via CDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Gulp is a helper to manage your project locally, not by connecting to external sources.

A common approach would be to manage current library versions by a package manager like [Bower](http://bower.io) – there is an [integration bridge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files) available (didn't test it though, I just update packages manually).

Comment: I assume when you say 'update packages manually' you mean download them and refer them locally or are you just updating the CDN links to them by changing their version number?

Comment: Yes, either downloading them manually or using `bower update [jquery]` to pull a new version before running gulp.

Comment: Think for the time being it looks as if we're going to download the latest version and stick with that.  Then if there is a need to get a more updated version we can just download it again.  Certainly seems a lot easier I think for the mo.